# Adding Progress bar in Django by fetching percent from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to implement a progress bar that shows the percentage completed of a task. The percentage completed can be fetched by a POST request.

The URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkScanStatus` and the parameter contains `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and a `userInstance`. This return a `JSON` response in the form {"Spider":20}. I want to continuously trigger this URL, get the response and display it in progress bar. I have completed the `Django` part, I need help on how to implement the progress bar for this in `HTML, JS, JQuery or AJAX`.

Here is the HTML code I am trying

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit','#scanForm', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // This AJAX request is for my main task submission
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/scanner/',
        data: {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            context: $('#context').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            uniqueUserInstance:$('input[name=uniqueUserInstance]').val(),
        },
        success:function(response){
            alert('Scan Completed');
            location.reload();
        }
    });

    //Here I want the AJAX call to fetch response and display it in progress bar
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/scanner/checkScanStatus',
        data: {
            userInstance : $('input[name=uniqueUserInstance]').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success:function(response){
          //What to code here. I want this function to trigger continuously until response is 100%           
           }
    });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to sedn ajax request to `checkScanStatus` per second?

Comment: Yes, and based on the JSON response I recieve I want to render the percent completed on a progress bar

Comment: Then just add setInterval for your ajax request till progress bar is 100%

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your AJAX call to `checkScanStatus` on an interval you should wrap it in an `setInterval`:

```
const intervalLength = 1000;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/scanner/checkScanStatus',
        data: {
            userInstance : $('input[name=uniqueUserInstance]').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success:function(response){
            // Do visualization stuff then check if complete
            if (response.progress >= 100) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
    });
}, intervalLength);
```

Simple example of progress bar:

```js
let progress = 0;
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progressBar');
const bar = progressBar.querySelector('.bar')
const progressBarText = progressBar.querySelector('h3');
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    progress += 23;
  if (progress >= 100) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    bar.style.width = '100%';
      progressBarText.innerHTML = '100%';
  } else {
    bar.style.width = progress + '%';
      progressBarText.innerHTML = `${progress} %`;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.progressBar {
  width: 400px;
}
.bar {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #bada55;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  transition: width 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0.64, 0, 1.26)
}
```

```html
<div class="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <h3>0 %</h3>
</div>
```